# Set optimal gas limit in web3.js

Tags: ethereum

I want to set gaslimit dynamically according to the need. When i am running code with static value like 170000, code runs well. But when i am using web3.eth.estimateGas() to dynamically assign gasLimit in truffle.js

```
var web3=require('web3');
module.exports = {
  networks: {    
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 2656,
  network_id: "*", // Match any network id
  gas:web3.eth.estimateGas({from:web3.eth.accounts[0]}),
  gasPrice:0
}
}
};
```

I am getting following error when i migrate my project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the module?

run npm install web3, and then try running your code again

Comment: Yes I tried installing web3 in IDE. still not working. So i also tried writing var web3=require('web3') above the code. still it didn't work

Comment: Don't run in your ide. Go to the directory where you are running your project and from the command line type: npm install web3. It will be installed in a node_modules folder under your project directory

Comment: i did the same what you told. But it isn't installing web3 module